# Socket Programming - Weird Behavior

Tags: c++, sockets, http, posix

I am trying to build an HTTP client. So far I have something that takes an ip address and prints the http response, no problem. But when I try to take that response and put it into a string the program hangs.

So this works:

```
write(sockfd, sendBuff, strlen(sendBuff));
string s = "";

while((n = read(sockfd, recvBuff, sizeof(recvBuff)-1)) > 0)
{
    recvBuff[n] = 0;
    if(fputs(recvBuff, stdout) == EOF)
    {
        printf("\n Error : Fputs error\n");
    }
}
```

And this doesnt:

```
write(sockfd, sendBuff, strlen(sendBuff));
string s = "";

while((n = read(sockfd, recvBuff, sizeof(recvBuff)-1)) > 0)
{
    recvBuff[n] = 0;
    s.append(recvBuff, strlen(recvBuff));
}
```

I'd really like to put an entire http response into a single string because I have an object that parses entire responses. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Why don't you just use `n` instead of putting a `0` at position `n` and then seeing how far that `0` is from the beginning of the string?

Comment: What is the problem? Except for the word "hangs", I do not see any other info. What does the debugger tell? To compare with snippet 1, can you print `s` after appending?

Comment: That code's fine (though for `append` there's no need to set `recvBuff[n]` to `0` or call `strlen`, just use `n` as the 2nd append parameter).  Perhaps your socket dropped during testing?  Why not put both `fputs` and `s.append` in and see if they correspond on a particular run?

Comment: Well say for example I go to a small web page - the above pattern works fine. But if I go to a massive page like the google home page my program will hang as if it entered an infinite loop. Even leaving it for several minutes it won't finish.

Comment: Maybe the server does not close the connection, in order to push 'live' events when they happen on the server side

Comment: K-ballo you are completely right! I feel like an idiot but yes it's the connection that hangs. Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using a stringstream to store the output?  You could do something like the following:

```
write(sockfd, sendBuff, strlen(sendBuff));
stringstream s;
s.str(""); // resets the internal string

while((n = read(sockfd, recvBuff, sizeof(recvBuff)-1)) > 0)
{
    recvBuff[n] = 0;
    s << recvBuff;
}
```

Then when you go to process the resulting string, you can get to it through the internal string buffer using:

```
s.str();
```

I have used this before many time when I have to build up a string for processing from differing parts.  Your mileage may vary.  Compile and try for yourself.  I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You are reading from the socket in a continuous loop until the socket errors or disconnects, which is the completely wrong thing to do when handling HTTP.  For one thing, the server may not close the connection at the end of the response, which would deadlock your code.

HTTP messages have structure to them, but you are completely ignoring that fact.
To **correctly** read an HTTP response, you need to follow the rules outlined in [RFC 2616 Section 4.4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-4.4) in order to know the structure of the response, which governs how to read the response and how to know when the response is complete.